# Delete row(s) with respect to username

Tags: php, mysqli, delete-row

i've gone through most of the questions similar to this but none addressed my problem.
i have table with four columns : **id**,**username**,**title** and **date**. i want to delete the entire row(s) associated with a specific username when the user clicks a button (anchor tag). pls, how do i achieve this? heres the code i tried.

**php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$dbconn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','notesdb');
if(!$dbconn){
 die("Connection failed:". mysqli_connect_error($dbconn));
}
if($stmt = $dbconn->prepare("DELETE * FROM notes_log where username = ? ")){
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$uname);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
}else{
 echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
mysqli_close();
// redirect user after delete is successful
header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="deleteAll.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete all</a>
```

The above code redirected the page but nothing was deleted.

Comment: did you check for mysqli_error? What do you see when you do not redirect?

Comment: What's inside `$SESSION['username']`? (Try to var_dump() it to check the value! Are you sure that it contains the right username? The script show any error message after click in the button?

Comment: @Jeff i just checked and yes i do get the error message, do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the current user or some user in a table (other then the current user) `i want to delete the entire row(s) associated with a specific username`  Also one minor thing `echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";` and then calling `header` is not going to treat you well.

Comment: @EliasSoares it does contain the right username, i just verified too

Comment: @Nick the same one i echoed "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement."

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the current user

Comment: @henrie You should print `$dbconn->error` to see the SQL error.

Comment: The asterisk isn't something that DELETE uses, only SELECT can. References: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html and an aggregate function such as [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `*` in the query. The syntax is just:

```
DELETE FROM notes_log where username = ?
```

See [DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

In a multi-table `DELETE` you need to put the table names after `DELETE`, but a single-table `DELETE` should have nothing there.

And when an SQL operation fails, you should print the SQL error message, not just `could not prepare SQL statement`, e.g.

```
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement: " . $dbconn->error;
```

Edit: `mysqli_close()` requires a database connection as its only argument.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

You will need to use `mysqli_close($dbconn)`.